# CAS -Apereo Jasig: How to redirect to a custom web page after a successful login?

Tags: java, spring, cas, jasig

I am new to Spring and I am utilizing Jasig-CAS 4.1.4 in my spring (4.3.0) project. The project is modularized one and I have implemented the CAS as another module. I have copied the original cas view and modified it goes with the project. So, I have set the CAS login page after modifying jsp views and set it as admin module's login page.
 I have configured the primary authentication by using jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler and it works very well. So, I need to redirect to the admin's home page when the login is succeeded. But I have no idea how to do it or where to do it.

Will anybody be able to help me with this?
(P.S. I tried some things with login-webflow.xml. but didn't work it out.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/cas/login?service=where-you-want-to-go
```